# pass/propagate event.target of parent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<a onClick={handlePageClick}>
        ← <span classname{'example'}>Previous</span>
 </a>
```

When a user clicks `←`, the `event.target` is `<a>`. When a user clicks on the nested `<span>`, "`Previous`", the `event.target` is `<span>`. How can I have my user click on `Previous`, but pass the element it is nested in (`<a>`)?

Comment: Use [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead. The current target is the element that has the event handler attached to.

Comment: Could not find that I was looking for exactly this, I marked it as a duplicate.